# Calling a wcf service method from Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, methods, service

I need to call a wcf service method in my project, if I have a method called getPrimaryList, how do I call it?

```
[OperationContract]
        public List<PrimaryClass> getPrimaryList()
        {
            string priConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            var priList = new List<PrimaryClass>();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(priConn))
            {
                const string sql = @"SELECT PrimarySchool,TopHonour,Cca,TopStudent,TopAggregate,TopImage FROM [Primary]";
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
                {
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(
                        CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                    if (dr != null)
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            var pri = new PrimaryClass
                            {
                                PrimarySchool = dr.GetString(0),
                                TopHonour = dr.GetString(1),
                                Cca = dr.GetString(2),
                                TopStudent = dr.GetString(3),
                                TopAggregate = dr.GetString(4),
                                TopImage = dr.GetString(5)
                            };
                            priList.Add(pri);
                        }
                    return priList;

                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the project that needs to call the service.
Add a Service Reference to the WCF Service.
Make an instance of the generated proxy/client class and call the method.

(this answer is nearly as general as your question, if you need more details you have to ask for them specifically)

**EDIT**

Example (the use of the dispatcher is not really needed here):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var proxy = new ServiceReference1.HelloWorldServiceClient();
    proxy.SayHelloCompleted += proxy_SayHelloCompleted;
    proxy.SayHelloAsync(_nameInput.Text);
}

void proxy_SayHelloCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.SayHelloCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () => _outputLabel.Text = e.Result
        );
    }
    else
    {
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            () => _outputLabel.Text = e.Error.Message
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: let's say i want to use a button to call the service how do i do it?

Comment: I added some code assuming you wanted to do this from within silverlight

Comment: this is roughly what i am looking for but can you explain to me what this 2 lines of codes does? proxy.SayHelloCompleted += proxy_SayHelloCompleted; 
proxy.SayHelloAsync(_nameInput.Text);

Comment: In silverlight you cannot call a method synchronously. So what you do is register for the matching completed event that will be raised as soon as the service call returns. After that you call the Async version of the method. This event and the Async method are generated by Visual Studio when you set the service reference.

Comment: BTW: you already asked about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5974789/help-with-explanation wasn't that clear?

Comment: yea i kinda posted this first before posting that, thought i'd zoom in on my problem but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Say you want to invoke the service on button_click..

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{     
   var client = new ServiceReference1.MyWCFServiceClient(); 
   var result = client.getPrimaryList();
   //do something here with the result now....
}
```