# Help with explanation

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, methods, service

I have some codes that i find very hard to understand. Can someone help me break it down line by line?

```
Service1Client client = new Service1Client();
            client.getPrimaryListCompleted += new EventHandler<getPrimaryListCompletedEventArgs>(AddPrimaryMarkerGraphics);
            client.getPrimaryListAsync();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first line creates an instance of the class `Service1Client`.

The second line hooks up an event handler for the event `getPrimaryListCompleted`.

the third line starts an asynchronous request. When there is a response, the `getPrimaryListCompleted` will be triggered so that the event handler can use the response.

Comment: when u say response, what are you referring to?

Comment: @redevil: The response is what the asynchronous call gets as an answer to the request that it sends. In this case it would be a service message containing a "PrimaryList", whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new `ServiceClient` called client.
2. Add an event handler to client so that when Primary List Function is completed the function `AddPrimaryMarkerGraphics` is automatically called.
3. Call the client function `getPrimaryListAsync()` (Async means that this function will be executed asynchronously ie: on another thread)

Answer (score 0):

This `Service1Client client = new Service1Client();` creates a new object of type `Service1Client()` which presumably is a client for calling a WCF service.

Then is attaches an event handler which will get called when the client raises the specified event.

The last line starts an asynchroneous service call (means its running in the background on a separate thread). Once that call has completed it probably raises the `getPrimaryListCompleted` event so the event handler will be called.